# Selenium - Find next element after a class

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I am new to Selenium and using to get products information from a website. Everything is legal :)

I am trying to get the text in P after P with class='description' found. How can I get the P's value? Schema is like below...

```
<p class="description"></p>
<p>...........</p> <!-- I need this tag's text -->
```

Or, I would like to add the HTML Tree to locate the P that I want.

[image]

I have the following code to get the P with class="description", but how do I get next one

```
IList<IWebElement> aciklama = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".content .urun_detay .padding20 .white > .row > .col-md-6 > .aciklama"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use following:

```
IList<IWebElement> aciklama = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//p[@class='aciklama']/following-sibling::p"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `~` to get sibling with `CssSelector`

```
IList<IWebElement> aciklama = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".content.urun_detay.padding20.white > .row > .col-md-6 > .aciklama ~ p"));
```

You can use the `<p>` tag or an attribute like class, id etc.

By the way, in `.content .urun_detay .padding20 .white` you are looking for an element with class `white` witch is decedent of an element with class `padding20` witch is decedent of an element with class `urun_detay` and so on. In `.content.urun_detay.padding20.white` without spaces you are looking for an element with all those classes.

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ By the way, I'm guessing `class="description"` and `class="aciklama"` are the same element?

Comment: @ArifYILMAZ Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`+` operator fot next sibling

```
IList<IWebElement> aciklama = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".aciklama + p"));
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)